# (preferably boost) lock-free array/vector/map/etc?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, multidimensional-array, lock-free

Considering my lack of c++ knowledge, please try to read my intent and not my poor technical question.

This is the backbone of my program https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/experimental/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp

I'm building a websocket server with websocket++ (and oh is websocket++ sweet.  I highly recommend), and I can easily manipulate per user data thread-safely because it really doesn't need to be manipulated by different threads; however, I do want to be able to write to an array (I'm going to use the catch-all term "array" from weaker languages like vb, php, js) in one function thread (with multiple iterations that could be running simultanously) and also read in 1 or more threads.

Take stack as an example: if I wanted to have all of the `id`s (`PRIMARY` column of all articles) sorted in a particular way, in this case by net votes, and held in memory, I'm thinking I would have a function that's called in its' own `boost::thread`, fired whenever a vote on the site comes in to reorder the array.

How can I do this without locking & blocking?  I'm 100% fine with users reading from an old array while another is being built, but I absolutely do not want their reads or the thread writes to ever fail/be blocked.

Does a lock-free array exist?  If not, is there some way to build the new array in a temporary array and then write it to the actual array when the building is finished without locking & blocking?

Comment: I'm not sure where your requirement to avoid locking/blocking comes from, or how strict it is, but if you built the "array" in a temporary data structure (while the original was being used for accesses), you could use the standard STL `swap()` operation to swap it into place when it is finished.  This is not atomic and so would require a lock for the duration of the swap operation, but it is a relatively "fast" operation, so your "array" would not be locked for very long and it is "safe".  (Re your qn, I personally don't know of any way to do what you ask in C++ without locking/blocking.)

Comment: (You would want to use a "readers/writers" locking pattern if you did implement this with `swap()` per my previous comment, btw.)

Comment: This whole question is screaming "premature optimization" to me. Have you actually profiled your program running in a real-world scenario and shown that the minimal locks you'd get from something like @Turix's approach are causing problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/lockfree.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Uh, uh, uh. Complicated.

Look here (for an example): [RCU](http://lwn.net/Articles/262464/) -- and this is only about multiple reads along with ONE write.

My guess is that multiple writers at once are not going to work. You should rather look for a more efficient representation than an array, one that allows for faster updates. How about a balanced tree? log(n) should never block anything in a noticeable fashion.

Regarding boost -- I'm happy that it finally has proper support for thread synchronization.

Of course, you could also keep a copy and batch the updates. Then a background process merges the updates and copies the result for the readers.

Comment: maybe try a database index. MySQL can store tables and indexes in RAM.